# How To Disable WooCommerce Address Formatting in the Admin Order View

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to figure out how to reformat the address for non-western orders in WooCommerce.

In WooCommerce, when you login to the admin and view an order that has a non-Western address (China for example), it reformats the address. For people shipping from a Western country, it's confusing (as I'm sure it is the other way around).

I've tried the following, which will let me remove fields, but it doesn't seem to allow me to order. Something is overriding this when I view an order from China. My default language is Australian English.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_shipping_address' , 'woo_reorder_shipping_fields', 10, 2 );
function woo_reorder_shipping_fields( $address, $wc_order ) {
    $address = array(
        'first_name'    => $wc_order->shipping_first_name,
        'last_name'    => $wc_order->shipping_last_name,
        'company'    => $wc_order->shipping_company,
        'address_1'    => $wc_order->shipping_address_1,
        'address_2'    => $wc_order->shipping_address_2,
        'city'    => $wc_order->shipping_city,
        'state'    => $wc_order->shipping_state,
        'postcode'    => $wc_order->shipping_postcode,
        'country'    => $wc_order->shipping_country
    );
    return $address;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a bit of research and trying a number of different overrides, I found the best solution here is the [WooComerce Booster](http://booster.io). It has a built-in setting that allows for changing the address format and allows you to set each country differently or set them all the same.

If you want to do it for just one country (or without a plugin), you can use the following code in your functions.php of your child theme.

```
function custom_address_formats( $formats ) {
    $formats[ 'US' ]  = "{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{postcode} {city} {state}\n{country}";
    return $formats;
}
add_filter( 'my_address_formats', 'custom_address_formats', 20 );
```

Simply create the above code for each country you want to modify, replacing the "US" with the two-letter country code of the country you want to modify.